# Serialize query expression (or hint) in plain C

Tags: serialization, tree, expression

We have an automated vending machine (avm with a plain c program) that work on data serialized in some binary files : currently for example the avm need a file for the products (products.bin), one file for listing products that could be not be sell together (no_cohabitation.bin).

Often the file no_cohabitation.bin lists (hardcode) various products according to a specific criterion (but this can vary): for example, if the vending machine is used to dispense medication and we can not sell all products for the heart and those causing the tachycardia => we must indicate for each product the listing or a pointer to a list of all those that cause tachycardia and we need to update this list each time a new dangerous product is added...

Here a fictionnal sample of how the files are working :

```
products.bin :
    Id (Int) => 1 
    Language char (60) => Avlocardyl (for the heart) 
         Properties (a key value pair loop) 
              "Good_ForHeart" TRUE 
    Id (Int) => 2 
    Language char (60) => SICATOL-1 (can cause the tachycardia) 
         Properties (a key value pair loop) 
               "Good_ForHeart" : FALSE
               "DANGEROUS_ForHeart": TRUE 

     ... 
    Id (Int) => 846 
    Language char (60) => SICATOL-846 (may cause the tachycardia) 
         Properties (a key value pair loop) 
               "Good_ForHeart" : FALSE
               "DANGEROUS_ForHeart": TRUE 


  no_cohabitation.bin: 
      ProductId (Int) => 1 
         Incompatibilities length (Int) => 845  ( a loop of all products incompatible with the product 1)
            IncomaptibleProductId (Int) => 2 
             ... 
            IncomaptibleProductId (Int) => 846
```

I am looking for a way to serialize a query (or query filter expression) in my file no_cohabitation.bin to indicate how to find the products incompatible with the one with Id=1...

Is there any way to do that ? I have heard of linq expression tree in c#, may be there is a similar api for plain c?

Comment: No, there is no LINQ expression tree equivalent in C. Your best bet would be to write a string represening your query in a custom syntax in no_cohabitation.bin and parse it.

Comment: Do you mean that I should integrate some sort of custom SQL...